# canvas to image Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, facebook, canvas

I am getting a picture from facebook api with **$scope.picture.picture.data.url** it correctly renders it to canvas but when I want to change it to **dataUrl** it get me this error

> canvas to image Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported.

canvas is rendered like this

```
 var canv=document.getElementById("mainCanvasD");
       var ctx = canv.getContext('2d');

       ctx.clearRect(0,0,540,320);
       // $scope.picture used here
       // draw games background image here 
       // console.log($scope.picture.picture.data.url);

       drawUrlImage($scope.picture.picture.data.url,10,130,180,180,"mainCanvasD");
       drawUrlImage("http://localhost/ezone/public/game/"+$scope.gameName+"/right/"+generateRandom(6)+".jpg",240,130,180,180,"mainCanvasD");
```

and am using this code to chnage it to dataUrl

```
 var canv=document.getElementById("mainCanvasD");

   var dataURL = canv.toDataURL('image/jpg');
   documentData={"image":dataURL,"gameName":$scope.gameName,"userId":$scope.userId,"gameId":$scope.gameId};
```

Comment: I think I do remember FB's graph API does send the proper request headers so setting the crossOrigin attribute to 'anonymous' should be enough to make this work on browsers that do implement this attribute.

Comment: its not working for me

Answer (score 4):

For security reasons you cannot access the content of a canvas if you draw something onto it which comes outside of your domain, in this case an image from facebook. 
The canvas becomes tainted in this case. You can still draw other stuff to it, the user sees it, but you are not allowed to programatically read it anymore.

Comment: so What is best solution here

Comment: The question is what do you want to do. Since it would be a serious security problem you cannot just download images without the user's interaction. If the image is publicly available with an url, you can download it server side, if not you can ask the user to upload it on your site.

Comment: Its a facebook app,am downloading a user profile on canvas and uploading to server as an image

Comment: In this case you have an access token that grants access to the user's images. you can upload this token to your server and then it can download images in the user's name.

Comment: I'm not familiar with facebook apps, but can you try this? It might work in this case. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_enabled_image