# drawing images using canvas not working in angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I would like to crop part of a video that is being played after click of the user. But I am guetting the following error:

> ERROR DOMException: Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported.

Similar question has already been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34574137/canvas-to-image-failed-to-execute-todataurl-on-htmlcanvaselement-tainted-ca) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32880641/canvascontext2d-drawimage-issue-onload-and-cors), but they do not solve my issue.

template

```
<div>
  <video src="url" #myvideo> </video>
  <div class="my-div" (click)="clickBox()" #divPos></div>
<div>
```

component

```js
clickVideo() {
  this.clickEvent = Observable.fromEvent(this.divPos.nativeElement, 'click')
  .map(event =>  event);
  this.clickEvent.subscribe(event => {
    const canvas: HTMLCanvasElement = this.renderer.createElement('canvas');
    const img = this.renderer.createElement('img');
    let context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    context.drawImage(this.myvideo.nativeElement, event.pageX-10, event.pageY-10, 30, 30);
    let data = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
    img.setAttribute('src', data);
    this.renderer.appendChild(document.body, img);
  })
}
```

Comment: Sorry, answered the wrong question earlier. Are you testing this from a local drive? Using the file:// protocol?

Comment: Why do you mean by testing from a local drive? Because my video is fetched from the server and I want to take picture from that video. So I am not using anything from the drive

Comment: Because that's one of the reasons for getting the 'Tainted' error. You mentioned that the error was on the 'context.drawImage' line, but the error 'Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement' would mean it was on the 'let data = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');' line. Which one is it exactly?

Comment: As the error message stated, the error is thrown because of  `toDataURL` @StevePadmore; so that is the line causing the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally found the way around. I need to do these two things:

- The streaming server should enable CORS : `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`
- To address the tainted canvas server side, I change the video tag to the following `<video src="url" crossorigin="anonymous" #myvideo> </video>`

  Trying to set the video tag in the component function `clickVideo()` might not work as I learnt the hard way, because the client needs to track that information before loading the video.

Comment: Was just about to ask if it was a CORS issue. Glad you found the solution.